# Is it possible/ how can i set the weight of a lot of buttons such that each column takes up 1/3rd of the width of the screen?

Tags: android, xml

So i'm relatively new to Android Development and XML so I was wondering if it'd be possible to do as the title says. How do I make all of these columns of buttons such that each row of buttons is split up evenly between the three buttons that are being created. I assume i'm just missing something because I'm almost positive this is possible I must just not quite understand how to do it.

I'd very much appreciate any help! Also do ignore some of the button names vulgarity they're correspond to sounds that each button will play (This is going to be a soundboard app).

Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.soundboard.MainActivity">

<!-- a lot of buttons -->

<!-- row 1 -->
<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/button_ethanBradberry"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/button_stfu"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/button_haha"
    />

<!-- row 2 -->
<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_ethanBradberry"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/button_ohNowIGetIt"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_ohNowIGetIt"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_stfu"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_stfu"
    android:id="@+id/button_whatTheFuck"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_whatTheFuck"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/button_whyTheFuckULyin"
    />

<!-- row 3 -->
<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_ohNowIGetIt"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/button_whyYouHeffBeMad"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_whyYouHeffBeMad"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_whatTheFuck"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_whatTheFuck"
    android:id="@+id/button_niggaYouGay"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_niggaYouGay"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/button_hitMarker"
    />

<!-- row 4 -->
<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_whyYouHeffBeMad"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_whyYouHeffBeMad"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_whyYouHeffBeMad"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/button_itsATrap"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_itsATrap"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_niggaYouGay"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_niggaYouGay"
    android:id="@+id/button_shutUpAndTakeMyMoney"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_shutUpAndTakeMyMoney"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_hitMarker"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_hitMarker"
    android:id="@+id/button_smokeWeedEveryDay"
    />

<!-- row 5 -->
<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_itsATrap"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/button_stop"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_stop"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_shutUpAndTakeMyMoney"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_shutUpAndTakeMyMoney"
    android:id="@+id/button_wow"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_wow"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/button_twentyOne"
    />

<!-- row 6 -->
<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_stop"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/button_surpriseMotherFucker"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_surpriseMotherFucker"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_wow"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_wow"
    android:id="@+id/button17"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button17"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/button18"
    />

<!-- row 7 -->
<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_surpriseMotherFucker"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/button19"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button19"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button17"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button17"
    android:id="@+id/button20"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button20"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/button21"
    />

<!-- row 8 -->
<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button19"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button19"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button19"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/button22"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button22"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button20"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button20"
    android:id="@+id/button23"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button23"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/button24"
    />

<!-- row 9 -->
<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button22"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/button25"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button25"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button23"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button23"
    android:id="@+id/button26"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button26"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button24"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button24"
    android:id="@+id/button27"
    />

<!-- Ad -->

<!--
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Marcin Orlowski, i figured out how to get it in the way I desire because of your response. My XML is now like this below. Thank you again!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.android.soundboard.MainActivity"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
>

<!-- a lot of buttons -->

<!-- row 1 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="@string/ethan_bradberry"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_ethanBradberry"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/shut_the_fuck_up"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_stfu"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/HaHa"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_haha"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- row 2 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="@string/oh_now_i_get_it"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_ohNowIGetIt"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/what_the_fuck"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_whatTheFuck"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/lying"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_whyTheFuckULyin"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- row 3 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="@string/why_you_haff_be_mad"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_whyYouHeffBeMad"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/nigga_you_gay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_niggaYouGay"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/hit_marker"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_hitMarker"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- row 4 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="@string/its_a_trap"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_itsATrap"
    />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/shut_up_and_take_my_money"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_shutUpAndTakeMyMoney"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/_smoke_weed"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_smokeWeedEveryDay"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- row 5 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="@string/stop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_stop"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/wow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_wow"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/twenty_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_twentyOne"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- row 6 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="@string/Surprise_Mother_fucker"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_surpriseMotherFucker"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button17"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button18"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- row 7 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button19"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button20"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button21"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- row 8 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button22"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button23"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button24"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- row 9 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/button25"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/button26"
    />

<Button
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/button27"
    />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button28"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button29"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button30"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button31"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button32"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button33"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can i set the weight of a lot of buttons such that each column takes up 1/3rd of the width of the screen?

So you want 3 buttons in each rows with exatly the same width of 1/3rd or available space? You should wrap each row in horizontal `<LinearLayout>` with `layout_width="match_parent"`. Then you should put 3 buttons in it and set each button's `layout_width="match_parent"` **and** `layout_weight="1"`.

Alternatively, you instead of using `LinearLayout` for each row, you can use [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) from support library and then instead of using `layout_width` to set button width you use `app:layout_widthPercent="33%"`. In such case you do not need to set `layout_weight` but you need to include supportlibrary with your app so not always necessary.

I would also replace your `<RelativeLayout>` with `<LinearLayout>` with `orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is split your buttons into different layouts. for a grid like structure like I assume you want, you'd be best to use some `LinearLayout`'s like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 3"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 3"/>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will give you 3 rows of 3 buttons. The buttons all have an equal weight due to a `layout_width` of 0 and a weight that is equal to the other buttons. This way they split the space evenly between them.
Each row is in it's own linear layout so it stacks in the parent container which has a vertical orientation.

If you are planning on a static screen this is the way to go. If you have a variable number of elements you will want to look into a `GridView` or `RecyclerView`

Comment: Sorry, was there any reason for the instant downvote?